# Electrum crashes on launch, can not update Python, can not remove Electrum

Tags: 16.04, python, lts

I have Ubuntu 16.04. My old Electrum wallet crashes on start, but I can't install the latest version of Electrum because it requires Python 3.6.

```
:~/Downloads/Electrum-3.3.6$ ./setup.py
Error: Electrum requires Python version >= 3.6.1...
```

I can't update Electrum because Python is newest version:

```
:~/Downloads/Electrum-3.3.6$ sudo apt-get install python3.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3.6 is already the newest version (3.6.9-1+xenial1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

And I can't remove Electrum either in order to install a new version:

```
:~/Downloads/Electrum-3.3.6$ sudo apt remove electrum
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package electrum
```

Update 1:

```
:~/Downloads/Electrum-3.3.6$ sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools 

python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-setuptools is already the newest version (20.7.0-1).
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

then

```
:~/Downloads/Electrum-3.3.6$ python3 -m pip install --user Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz[fast]
Processing ./Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Error: Electrum requires Python version >= 3.6.1...
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-req-build-gwdsuxze/
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

then

```
:~/Downloads/Electrum-3.3.6$ pip install --upgrade pip
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 188kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-19.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.1.1
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Moving to /home/user/.local/bin/pip
   from /tmp/pip-uninstall-Jz4og3/pip
  Moving to /home/user/.local/bin/pip2
   from /tmp/pip-uninstall-Jz4og3/pip2
  Moving to /home/user/.local/bin/pip2.7
   from /tmp/pip-uninstall-Jz4og3/pip2.7
  Moving to /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-19.1.1.dist-info/
   from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/~ip-19.1.1.dist-info
  Moving to /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/
   from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/~ip
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

then

```
:~/Downloads/Electrum-3.3.6$ python3 Electrum-3.3.8/run_electrum
  File "Electrum-3.3.8/run_electrum", line 67
    sys.exit(f"Error: {str(e)}. Try 'sudo python3 -m pip install <module-name>'")
                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is your python version as it says you are using python 2.7

Comment: My Python version is 2.7.12

Comment: I have updated my answer please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

Download package:

```
wget https://download.electrum.org/3.3.8/Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz
```

Verify signature:

```
wget https://download.electrum.org/3.3.8/Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz.asc
gpg --verify Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz.asc
```

Run without installing:

```
tar -xvf Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz
python3 Electrum-3.3.8/run_electrum
```

Install with PIP:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pip
python3 -m pip install --user Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz[fast]
```

**Edit**
Python 2.7 will not be maintained past 2020. Originally, there was no official date. Recently, that date has been updated to January 1, 2020.

Please avoid using [Python 2.7](https://pythonclock.org/)

Comment: Thank you, but did not help. I updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: So I should update to 3.7? But As I know there are some problems with GUI if I do this.

Comment: But I have it on my system and as far as I know - there are no easy way to switch it to Python 3. So how can I use then Electrum?